# How to select all elements except those in subtrees of certain elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to match all elements inside HTML except those , that are inside certain elements.

It seems CSS3 does not support such a selector:

```
body *:not(.childclass *){
  transform:none;
}
```

any easy workaround?

Comment: Please share a basic markup structure and explain what do you need to (not) match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body :not(.childclass) * {
  transform:none;
}
```

you are trying to select wildcard (*) on a pseudo, which is not correct. 
I'll explain the code below:

```
body :not(.childclass) *
```

select all items inside any item without childclass inside a body tag.

There's no need on adding a wildcard before :not pseudo but you can add it if you want, it will interpret same

```
body :not(.childclass) *
```

than

```
body *:not(.childclass) *
```

as there's a whitespace between body and :not, it will interpret as all :not matching elements inside body tag.

In fact, you don't need the body tag on the selector:

```
:not(.childclass) *
```

Will match all elements inside tags without childclass.

But there's a workaround here. If you have a childclass inside a matching element, it will be selected as you are selecting it too with the wildcard, as an element inside a not childclass element that has inside a non childclass element inside a childclass element is a true match.

See:

https://jsfiddle.net/5nw6k3jL/

You'll need to specify the level for it, for example, for a two level matching elements:

```
:not(.childclass) :not(.childclass) * {  }
```

This will match all elements not inside childclass that are inside elements with not childclass.

You can also set more than a level in a row:

```
  :not(.childclass), :not(.childclass) :not(.childclass) * {  }
```

This will do the trick for both as latest has more priority.

If you don't know the tag level inside the layout, you can set a bunch of selectors in row or surrounding with it JavaScript.

Comment: This should have been a comment as it does not answer the question

Comment: It should be as answer as it does because it answers the question and that's the correct way to select properly all elements that are not children of a given class. By the other hand, there's no need on body tag at the begging of the selector to reach the desired effect but could be nice in terms of speed to set a parent as closer as possible.

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds with vanilla JS is to use `element.matches()` method.

```
var  els = document.querySelectorAll('*');
els.forEach((elem) => {
    if(!elem.matches(".childclass *")){
        elem.style.transform = 'none';
    }

});
```